# VBA: is there a way to get/read the module attributes?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), you can set the attributes of a module or a variable using the Attribute keyword. For instance

```
    ' Header
Attribute VB_Name = "ClassOrModuleName"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False ' ignored
Attribute VB_Creatable = False ' ignored
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False ' a Value of True creates a default global instance
Attribute VB_Exposed = True ' Controls how the class can be instanced.

'Module Scoped Variables
Attribute variableName.VB_VarUserMemId = 0 ' Zero indicates that this is the default member of the class.
Attribute variableName.VB_VarDescription = "some string" ' Adds the text to the Object Browser information for this variable.

'Procedures 
Attribute procName.VB_Description = "some string" ' Adds the text to the Object Browser information for the procedure.
Attribute procName.VB_UserMemId = someInteger
    '  0: Makes the function the default member of the class.
    ' -4: Specifies that the function returns an Enumerator.
```

More information about them in: https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/vb-attributes-what-are-they-and-why-should-we-use-them/

I was thinking, is there a way to get/read these attributes inside the code? For instance something like

```
Sub BarMacroName()
'
' BarMacroName Macro
' Bar Macro Description
'
    Dim var

    MsgBox VB_Description 'display this module's description
    MsgBox VB_Name 'display this module's description

End Sub
```

Not just the description and the name, but in general, can we actually read the attributes inside the code itself?

Edit: I'm specifically looking to see if you can extract the Attribute value within the VBA script itself. I'm researching malware vulnerabilities and I was curious if someone could embed malicious code within, let's say, the description of a VBA module.

Comment: I would try to extract it directly from [vbaProject.bin](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbaProject.bin)

Comment: @omegastripes I'm specifically looking to see if you can extract Attribute values within the script itself, not looking to extract them, I edited the original question to reflect that

Comment: Not directly as far as I know. You'd have to export the module and read the bas file.

Comment: @hyk So if you are researching the ability of embedding malicious VBA module attributes, then the question title should not be limited to get/read ops.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes there is a way to read annotations inside your VBA code.  You can view and modify attributes using Rubberduck, a free add-in to the MS Offce Visual Basic Editor.

Rubberduck *shows* existing attributes by adding annotations (basically a specially formatted comment) to your code.  Add attributes by adding annotations and clicking a sync button.  Remove attributes by deleted the commented annotation and clicking a sync button.

Here's an example of annotations in a code module.

```
'@Exposed
'@Folder("Class Libraries.Main.Book Sheet Range Project")
'@ModuleDescription("Class with functions and methods for working with Excel Workbooks.")
'@PredeclaredID
Option Explicit
```

Rubberduck warns the user when an annotation and attribute are out of sync and allows you to sync it to whichever one is correct.

The add-in does much more than managing annotations and is definitely worth checking out.  If nothing else, it beats the alternative:  exporting your modules, modifying attributes in Notepad and re-importing them to your project.

[Rubberduck VBA:  Annotations](https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations)

Comment: I'll also add this link to the [RubberDuck Features](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features) page.  Take a quick look and you'll understand why I love RubberDuck.